# jQuery slideDown not working without slideUP

Tags: jquery

I am working on an animated Sticky Header. Once you scroll below a certain point a header should slide in from the top and remain fixed till you scroll back above the point.

Here is the jsfiddle, if you remove the comment on slideUP, it works fine.

http://jsfiddle.net/rkr2/Dk8UA/1/

HTML:

```
<div class="nav-container">
    <div class="nav">
        <div id="bad"> </div>
    </div>
</div>
<p> long content here </p>
```

CSS:

```
.f-nav{
     z-index: 9999;
     position: fixed;
     left: 0;
     top: 0;
     width: 100%;
}

#bad{
     width: 100%;
     height: 50px;
     background-color: yellow;
}
```

JS:

```
var nav=$('.nav-container');
$(window).scroll(function(){
    if($(this).scrollTop() > 200) {
        nav.addClass('f-nav');
        nav.slideDown('slow');
        $('#bad').css('background-color','red');
    } else {
        nav.removeClass('f-nav');
        //nav.slideUp('slow');
        $('#bad').css('background-color','yellow');
    }
});
```

Why is this happening?

Comment: It works fine for me on jsfiddle without the slideUp

Comment: @rk. Thats is because when you are scrolling up you always do a slidUp so the nav is not showing up...

Comment: For me too only when you change height of result window for smallest.

Comment: @PSCoder I know that, the problem is, when I am not using slideUp, the 'sliding' of slideDown doesn't work. It just pops-up to say.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jQuery slideDown are meant to work on hidden elements. If the element is already visible you'll not see the effect. To work around this add `.hide()` on the element before `.slideDown`. Like this: http://jsfiddle.net/Dk8UA/3/

The reason it works when adding `.slideUp`, is that slideUp hides the element.

*Update:*
You can add an if condition to check if the nav already has the class to avoid doing the animation every time you scroll.

```
var nav = $('.nav-container');
$(window).scroll(function () {
    if ($(this).scrollTop() > 200) {
        if (!nav.hasClass('f-nav')) {
            nav.addClass("f-nav");
            nav.hide();
            nav.slideDown("slow");
            $('#bad').css('background-color', 'red');
        }
    } else {
        nav.removeClass("f-nav");
        // nav.slideUp("slow");
        $('#bad').css('background-color', 'yellow');
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Dk8UA/13/

Comment: Btw, is there any way to stop it from resetting everytime I scroll? I need it to be fixed as the header.

Comment: Yes. Updated the answer to reflect your comment. Notice the `if (!nav.hasClass('f-nav'))`